# Python PIL move image up

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have an image (1920x1080) and I need to move all pixel up in the y-directions for e.g. 100 pixels.

I have used the following code:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(sImage)

    pix = img.load()
    for x in range(1,1919):
        for y in range(1,1079):
            pix[x,y] = pix[x, y+100] #shift y
    
    img.show()
```

When shifting the pixels more than 1 pixel up I receive the error message "image index out of range", what makes totally sense.
What I need here is that the image still have 1920x1080 pixels and all "new" pixels at the bottom of the image shall be black. The whole image shall just be moved in the 1920x1080 zone without increasing the number of pixels.
Is there any function which can do that or can I prevent the error message "image index out of range" somehow?

Comment: Shift is it crop image.

Comment: Hi @AlexAlex. Can you describe that to me in more detail? I don't want to crop the picture because the picture can be different and moved for different amount of pixels. For example when I am using 'rotated_img = img.rotate(45)' it rotates the image and does not care about any ranges.

Comment: You can create a new black canvas, copy the box of the old image from y=100 to y=1080, and paste it onto the new black canvas.